# IBM MQ Send Message Using Java Program

Tags: java, jms, websphere, jndi, mq

I am trying to send messages to MQ Queue from the java program running on Websphere Application Server.
I configured QConnection Factory & Q jndis in Websphere Applciaiton server. But when running program I am getting error

```
Details: "com.ibm.ejs.jms.JMSConnectionFactoryHandle incompatible with javax.jms.QueueConnectionFactory".
        at com.ibm.bpm.rest.impl.service.ServiceRunner$TaskRunner.runService(ServiceRunner.java:1385)
        at com.ibm.bpm.rest.impl.service.StartActionHandler.handleActionGetModel(StartActionHandler.java:363)
        at com.ibm.bpm.rest.impl.playback.ServicePlaybackResourceImpl.createServicePlayback(ServicePlaybackResourceImpl.java:141)
        at com.ibm.bpm.rest.impl.playback.ServicePlaybackResource.createServicePlayback(ServicePlaybackResource.java:115)
        at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor742.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:55)
```

This is the program I am using. Any help is greatly appreciated.

```
public void putMessageViaCF3(String messageContent, String connectionFactory, String sendQName)
            throws MQException, IOException, NamingException, JMSException {
        Queue myQueue;
        QueueConnectionFactory myQueueFactory;
        QueueConnection connection = null;
        QueueSession session = null;
        try {
            InitialContext jndi = new InitialContext();
            myQueueFactory = (QueueConnectionFactory) jndi.lookup("jms/SORC_QM_CF");
            myQueue = (Queue) jndi.lookup("jms/SORC_SEND_Q");

            connection=myQueueFactory.createQueueConnection();

            session = connection.createQueueSession(true, Session.AUTO_ACKNOWLEDGE);

            QueueSender sender = session.createSender(myQueue);
            connection.start();
            TextMessage textMessage = session.createTextMessage("Test Harish");
            textMessage.setStringProperty("messageType", "file");
            sender.send(textMessage);

            sender.close();
            
        } finally {

            if (session != null) {
                session.close();
            }

            if (connection != null) {
                connection.close();
            }
        }

    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to [this resource from IBM](https://www.ibm.com/support/pages/javalangclasscastexception-error-occurs-during-jndi-lookup-queue-connection-factory) this kind of `ClassCastException` is seen when:

> ...a queue connection factory is defined as a WebSphere MQ **Connection Factory** instead of a WebSphere MQ **Queue Connection Factory**.

To resolve this you should either:

- Define the connection factory as a WebSphere MQ **Queue Connection Factory**.
- Use a `javax.jms.ConnectionFactory` object in the application code rather than a `javax.jms.QueueConnectionFactory` object.